# Error 00937 "not a single-group group function"

Tags: sql, oracle

i face ORA-00937: "not a single-group group function" error problem with this sql query:
Any ideas please ! Thanks.

```
SELECT avg(count(*)) as value, 'Taux remplissage' as serie, to_char(c.datcre, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as arg
from charge c left join emplac e ON c.adr = e.adr 
where e.ADR is not null and e.empsta != 'I' and e.empsta != 'V'
and (trunc(c.datcre) >= to_date('2020-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
and (trunc(c.datcre) <= to_date('2021-11-30','YYYY-MM-DD'))
GROUP BY to_char(c.datcre, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY arg, serie
```

Comment: The problem is `avg(count(*))`.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: i want to  calculate the filling rate of a store (the average value)

Comment: . . I should have clearer:  Provide sample data, desired, results, and a clear explanation *in the question*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by `avg(count(*))` in this context.  This would be used (in Oracle) in a context where you want a result set with one row.  But the `order by` suggests that you are expecting multiple rows.

If you just want the `count(*)` then you would use:

```
select count(*) as value, 'Taux remplissage' as serie, 
       to_char(c.datcre, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as arg
from charge c join
     emplac e 
     ON c.adr = e.adr 
where e.ADR is not null and e.empsta not in ('I', 'V') and
      c.datcre >= date '2020-11-01' and
      c.datcre < date '2021-12-01'
group by to_char(c.datcre, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by arg;
```

If you want the overall average on every row, you would use:

```
avg(count(*)) over () as average
```

Note the other changes to the query:

- `not in` is much simpler than a chain of `<>`s.
- Strictly speaking, the `is not null` is redundant, but I left it in.
- The `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join` anyway, so you should specify the `join` you are actually using.
- Oracle supports the Standard SQL syntax for date constants.  You might as well use it.
- The date comparisons are generally going to be more efficient when you remove functions on the column.  That helps the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from emplac) as value,'% remplissage ' || c.mag as serie, to_char(c.datcre, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as arg
from charge c left join emplac e ON c.adr = e.adr 
where e.ADR is not null and e.empsta != 'I'
and (trunc(c.datcre) >= to_date('2020-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
and (trunc(c.datcre) <= to_date('2021-11-30','YYYY-MM-DD'))
GROUP BY to_char(c.datcre, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), c.mag
ORDER BY arg
```